# How to Make a Stopwatch for a quiz system using java

Tags: java, applet, keyevent

I'm really stuck, thanks to my college.
I need code in Java to have a `Stopwatch` which shows time in `00:00:00(mm:ss:msms)` format.  I want to use Key events to run and pause and reset the timer. Like if I press S the stopwatch starts and P pauses and R resets.
 the thing is the I also want to add key events on numbers for teams, like if I press 1, the "team 1" flashes, preferably with a beep, and so on with `2` `3` `4` `5`. im not able to understand how to do this.

i wrote this to print time in second only just to try...

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class StopWatch2 extends JLabel
            implements KeyListener, ActionListener {

   private long startTime;                           

   private boolean running;  
   private Timer timer;  
   public StopWatch2() {
             super("  Press S  ", JLabel.CENTER);
      addKeyListener(this);
   }

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

       long time = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000;
       setText(Long.toString(time));
   }

   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

          int keyCode=e.getKeyCode();
      if (keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                     running = true;
         startTime = e.getWhen(); 
         setText("Running:  0 seconds");
         if (timer == null) {
            timer = new Timer(100,this);
            timer.start();
         }
         else
            timer.restart();
      }
      if(keyCode==KeyEvent.VK_P)
      {

         timer.stop();
         running = false;
         long endTime = e.getWhen();
         double seconds = (endTime - startTime) / 1000.0;
         setText("Time: " + seconds + " sec.");
      }
   }
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
   {}
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
   {}

} 




import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test2 extends JApplet {

   public void init() {

      StopWatch2 watch = new StopWatch2();
      watch.setFont( new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 24) );
      watch.setBackground(Color.white);
      watch.setForeground( new Color(180,0,0) );
      watch.setOpaque(true);
      getContentPane().add(watch, BorderLayout.CENTER);

   }

}
```

im trying stuff on my own n m pretty much self taught so im not able to understand whats going wrong

Comment: So what's your question? Are you expecting someone to just write this program for you?

Comment: *"...thanks to my college"*. What steps have *you* taken to solve the problem?

Comment: @giovanni: that would be the best!

Comment: @user1515834 i edited my post and added what i tried

Comment: @DougRamsey just edited my post

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like:

```
/**
 * Stopwatch is a simple timer.
 */
public class Stopwatch {

    /**
     * Stopwatch() Initialises a stopwatch.
     */
    public Stopwatch() {
        // Your code here.
    }

    /**
     * elapsed() The elapsed time in milliseconds shown on the stopwatch.
     *
     * @return double  The elapsed time in milliseconds as a double.  Returns -1.0 if no meaningful
     * value is available, i.e. if the watch is reset or has been started and not stopped.
     */
    public double elapsed() {
        // Your code here.
    }

    /**
     * start() Starts the stopwatch and clears the previous elapsed time.
     */
    public void start() {
        // Your code here.
    }

    /**
     * stop() If the stopwatch has been started this stops the stopwatch and calculates the
     * elapsed time.  Otherwise it does nothing.
     */
    public void stop() {
        // Your code here.
    }

    /**
     * reset() Resets the stopwatch and clears the elapsed time.
     */
    public void reset() {
        // Your code here.
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // Your code here.
    }

} // end class Stopwatch
```

Comment: somewhat, what i want is that the stopwatch should be centrally aligned and it should show time changing,

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to do to much in one place.  Separate out the stopwatch code into its own class.  Call that class as needed from the user interface methods.  Separate out your objects with the minimum interaction between them.  That makes design and coding easier.  You did design this program on paper before you started coding, didn't you?

Comment: @rossum- Are you saying there should be some sort of thought process involved before I just code myself into a corner that I have to code myself out of?!? Sounds like good advise!+1